# How to get date of post when using wp_get_recent_posts()?

Tags: posts, date, recent-posts

I get the latest posts this way:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

Then I loop through them and get information about the post this way:

```
$recent_posts[0]["post_title"]
```

How can I get the date the post was published?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see everything returned via php's [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $recent_posts );
echo '</pre>';
```

This will reveal that the date is stored in `post_date`:

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ):
    echo $recent['post_date'];
endforeach;
```

Or to format the date, use php's `date` and `strtotime`:

```
echo date( 'l F jS', strtotime( $recent['post_date'] ) );
```

Comment: There is one more thing though, it's displaying the date in enlgish even though the wp is configured in spanish (using the .mo file and the WPLANG variable).

Comment: Should I take this advice? http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Date_and_Time_Locale_Settings Seems like a hack more than a solution

Comment: you can use php's setlocale for date output in spanish, or WordPress's translation facilities that you have linked. what do you mean by not working on your server? how is it not working?

Comment: sorry for that, the cache plugin got me confused! I was coming back to delete the comments because I had figured it out! thanks for all the help!